# Run node server using gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am new to gulp.

I need to run node server using gulp but without using any of its plugin.

Is it possible?

If not then what is the best plugin for it in gulp system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try `gulp-nodemon` plugin. It's useful plugin for development with node.

```
// Gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon')
  , jshint = require('gulp-jshint')

gulp.task('lint', function () {
  gulp.src('./**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
})

gulp.task('develop', function () {
  nodemon({ script: 'server.js'
          , ext: 'html js'
          , ignore: ['ignored.js']
          , tasks: ['lint'] })
    .on('restart', function () {
      console.log('restarted!')
    })
})
```

For more details you can visit [here](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon).

**Also**

If you don't want use any plugin, you can start node without it like below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , exec = require('child_process').exec

gulp.task('nodestart', function (cb) {
  exec('node bin/www.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

Comment: what is exec in exec('node bin/www.js',?

Comment: you can run os commands with exec, as like as "mkdir app" or "cd folder" or another somethings.

Comment: exec = require('child_process').exec

Answer (score 3):

There are several plugins available with gulp.

1. Nodemon (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon)
2. Express (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-express)
3. Develop Server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-develop-server)

if you wish to start the node server without any plugin you can try out the following.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('start', function (callback) {
    exec('node server/app.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        callback(err);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in development environment [gulp-supervisor](https://github.com/leny/gulp-supervisor)

```
// Gulpfile.js
var gulp = require( "gulp" ),
    supervisor = require( "gulp-supervisor" );

gulp.task( "supervisor-simple", function() {
    supervisor( "test/fixture/server.js" );
} );

gulp.task( "supervisor-all", function() {
    supervisor( "test/fixture/server.js", {
        args: [],
        watch: [ "test" ],
        ignore: [ "tasks" ],
        pollInterval: 500,
        extensions: [ "js" ],
        exec: "node",
        debug: true,
        debugBrk: false,
        harmony: true,
        noRestartOn: false,
        forceWatch: true,
        quiet: false
    } );
} );
```

if you are in production environment, i recommand gulp [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) plugin, [gulp-connect-pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-pm2)